# Como compara senha php com sql que foi inserida com PASSWORD

Tags: php, sql

Insiro a senha com o argumento PASSWORD na minha query exemplo.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, PASSWORD(value2), value3, ...);
```

Quero saber se tem como pegar o valor de um input para saber sé é igual, já tenho a senha em uma $_SESSION guardada quero saber como transformo a senha do input nesse tipo de criptografia e comparo.

Comment: Você deves informar qual versão do PHP estas usando bem como qual biblioteca de cryptografia assim como o que você de fato armazenou no seu banco de dados (hash's, playn-text, etc...).

Comment: Normalmente ao criar um usuário (registro) usa-se a senha informada pelo usuário para criar uma hash e esta hash é armazenada no banco de dados... a cada login o usuário insere a senha a aplicação então cria uma nova hash e faz a comparação com a hash armazenada. As hash's nunca são iguais más a biblioteca de cryptografia podes dizer se foram geradas apartir do mesmo valor (mesma senha).